# Отображение элементов JList без DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing

Пытаюсь вывести JList без `DefaultListModel`, используя свой собственный `List` и метод `add` для добавления в `JList`. Получаю список ошибок вида

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at javax.swing.JList$4.getSize(Unknown Source)

Задача стоит именно в выводе без `DefaultListModel`.

В конструкторе `MyForm()`

```
    import laba2.ACrafts;
import laba2.List;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class MyForm extends JFrame{
             JFrame formShow;
        private JList<ACrafts> list;
        public List li;
        private JButton btnAdd;

        public MyForm() {
            li = new List();
                JPanel panelShow = new JPanel();

            formShow = new JFrame("Aircrafts");
            formShow.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 550);
            formShow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            formShow.add(panelShow);
            panelShow.setLayout(null);

                    list = new JList<ACrafts>();
            list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
            list.setBounds(20, 20, 640, 150);
                    ACrafts[] arr;
                    arr = li.toArray();
                    list.setListData(arr);
                    panelShow.add(list);

            public void setData(ACrafts a) {
            li.add(a);      
        }
    }
```

Методы `add` в классе `List`

```
class Element{
    Element left;
    ACrafts data;
    Element right;  

}

public class List implements ListImpl{
     private Element first;
     private Element last;
     private int size;

        public List() {
            first = null;
            last = null;
            size = 0;
        }

    public void add(ACrafts e){
        Element elem = new Element();
        elem.data = e;
        if (size == 0)
            first = last = elem;
        else
            last.right = elem;
            elem.left = last;
            last = elem;
        size++;
    }
}
```

В мейне:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ACrafts[] aircraft = new ACrafts[5];

        aircraft[0] = new ACrafts("Boeing 767-300F","США",7130,54000,13100,850);
        aircraft[1] = new ACrafts("Airbus 310-300F","Франция",39000,9600,12200,850);
        aircraft[2] = new ACrafts("Boeing 757-200F","США",7100,39780,12500,935);
        aircraft[3] = new ACrafts("IL-86","Украина",3300,15000,11000,950);
        aircraft[4] = new ACrafts("Avro RJ-100","Великобритания",2255,9500,10600,890);

        MyForm form = new MyForm();

        form.setData(aircraft[0]);
        form.setData(aircraft[1]);
        form.setData(aircraft[2]);
        form.setData(aircraft[3]);
        form.setData(aircraft[4]);

        form.formShow.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Причем если сделать вывод списка по нажатию кнопки, то все выводится. А предыдущий вариант нет.

```
btnAdd = new JButton("Просмотреть");
        btnAdd.setBounds(30, 250, 100, 50);
        panelShow.add(btnAdd);
            btnAdd.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            ACraft[] petsArr;
            petsArr = li.toArray();
            z1.setListData(petsArr);} });

            z1 = new JList();
            z1.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
            z1.setBounds(20, 20, 640, 150);
            panelShow.add(z1);
```

Comment: То есть проблема просто в том, что список _не выводится_? То есть удаление не при чём?

Comment: @VladD, задача стоит все таки в удалении, но список даже не выводится. У меня до этого получалось выводить список с помощью DefaulfListModel, но при этом удалить элемент используя мой метод remove2 оказалось невозможным. Вопрос стоит в том, как реалиовать удаление?

Comment: Окей, но тогда давайте всё же разделим проблемы. (1) У вас не получается удалить элемент из DefaulfListModel (2) У вас не получается отобразить элементы другим способом. Мне кажется, это стоит задавать по отдельности. А вы задали вопрос, который не отражает ни одну из двух непосредственных проблем. Мне кажется, об основной задаче нужно лишь упомянуть в вопросе. (Я вообще-то не спец по awt, но кажется все спят уже.)